# ostream friend function of specialized template class

Tags: c++, templates, friend

```
template <> 
class test<int> {
    int y; 
public:     
    test(int k) : y(k) {}     
    friend ofstream& operator<< <test<int>> (ofstream& os, const test<int>& t); 
};  
template<> 
ofstream& operator<< <test<int> > (ofstream& os, const test<int>& t) 
{
    os << t.y;
    return os;
}
```

The code above is specialized template class of test in a int version. I am trying to overload ofstream operator<< function. But it shows error message;

> C2027: use of undefined type 'std::basic_ofstream<_Elem,_Traits>'

Besides, the same method works on a ordinary function (not ofstream operator<< but the function that I make) Is there anyway to us operator<< function of ofstream in a specialized template class ?

Comment: Have you included `<fstream>` or just `<ios_fwd>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include

```
 #include <iostream>
```

At the time of instantiation of the function template. Perhaps you only included

```
 #include <iosfwd>
```

Besides, you shouldn't be defining (static) friend as a template: **https://ideone.com/1HRlZ**

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename> class test;

template <> 
class test<int> {
    int y; 
public:     
    test(int k) : y(k) {}     
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const test& t); 
};  

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const test<int>& t) 
{
    return os << t.y;
}  

int main()
{
    test<int> a(42);
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

Note that it isn't a good idea to have 'using namespace std' in your header file, which is why I removed it from the sample. (*It might cause conflicts for users of your header file when they include your header*)

Comment: fixed another problem with the `ostream` operator that completes the test: https://ideone.com/1HRlZ

Comment: I actually included both header files but error didn't vanish

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of interesting issues here. First the obvious housekeeping

- You should `#include <fstream>` and don't forget `using namespace std`.
- `operator <<` shouldn't be a template, it should be an overloaded function.
- `os << t.y` confuses the compiler for me (g++ 4.4.3: *"warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second:"*). You intend to push the int to the stream obviously, but the compiler notices that an `int` can be turned into a `test<int>` via your constructor and therefore it doesn't know whether you want to push an `int` or a `test<int>`. This is stupid I know, and can be solved by making the constructor `explicit`.

  ```
  #include <fstream>
  using namespace std;
  template <typename T>
  class test;

  template <>
  class test<int> {
      int y;
  public:
      explicit test(int k) : y(k) {}
      // friend ofstream& operator<<   < test<int> > (ofstream& os, const test<int>& t); 
      friend ofstream& operator<< (ofstream& os, const test<int>& t);
  };
  // template<> 
  // ofstream& operator<< <test<int> > (ofstream& os, const test<int>& t) 
  ofstream& operator<<  (ofstream& os, const test<int>& t)
  {
      os << t.y;
      return os;
  }
  int main() {
  }
  ```